# Routing request to same service registered as two different service-ID

Tags: spring-boot, netflix-eureka, netflix-zuul

In my spring boot application, I m using Eureka server for the discovery service.
In one of my Discovery client application I am using zuul proxy to route the requests to different services registered with the Discovery Server.

I have one resource application which is responsible for storing the data into the db. I have created two instances for this service registered as two different service with the discovery service.
The api published for this service lets say is /resources Get,Post, etc

The client application sends request like /definitions and /locations for the two instances of this resource service.

Now my problem is I want to map this /definitions to service-id 1/resources and locations to /service-id2/resources.

I m not sure how to do this as when I send /defnitions from the client application it expects /definitions to be there in the resource application which is not the case.

I am trying something like this 
`zuul:
  routes:
    locations:
      path: /locations/**
      rewrite: /resources/**
      serviceId: location_service
      stripPrefix: false
    definitions:
      path: /definitions/**
      rewrite: /resources/**
      serviceId: definition_service
      stripPrefix: false`

Comment: did you find a working solution ?

Answer (score 1):

you are using `stripPrefix: false` in both cases. It means zuul will not cut it from request url and pass to your proxied service. Try to play with that.

At least in spring-cloud org.springframework.cloud.netflix.zuul.filters.ZuulProperties file there is no 'rewrite' property, are you sure its correct?